# Second Level Expansion?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

First of all, sorry if this sounds too simple. I'm new to cakePHP by the way.

My objective is to expand the `team_id` in `season` controller where it linked thru `standings` table.

My current model rule are:

1. Each season has many standings
2. Each standings denotes a team.
3. Basically is a many to many relation between season and team = standings.

Here's my SeasonController:

```
class SeasonsController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function view($id)
    {
        $this->Season->id = $id;
        $this->set('season', $this->Season->read());
    }
}
```

When I browse a single season thru `/cakephp/seasons/view/1`, the `$season` array shows:

```
Array
(
    [Season] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => English Premier League 2013/2014
            [start] => 1350379014
            [end] => 0
        )

    [Standing] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [team_id] => 1
                    [win] => 1
                    [lose] => 0
                    [draw] => 1
                    [GF] => 5
                    [GA] => 4
                    [season_id] => 1
                    [rank] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [team_id] => 2
                    [win] => 0
                    [lose] => 1
                    [draw] => 1
                    [GF] => 4
                    [GA] => 5
                    [season_id] => 1
                    [rank] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

The result only shows `team_id`, but how can I get further expansion for `team_id`?

I have put below in my Team's model, but still doesn't auto linked. Below are all my models:

```
class Team extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Team';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Standing' => array(
            'className' => 'Standing'
        ));
}

class Season extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Season';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Standing' => array(
            'className' => 'Standing'
        ));
}

class Standing extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Standing';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Team' => array(
            'className' => 'Team',
            'foreignKey' => 'team_id',
            ),

        'Season' => array(
            'className' => 'Season',
            'foreignKey' => 'season_id',
            ),

        );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Use CakePHP's [[Containable]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containable) behavior.

---

**Explanation & Code example:**

"Containable" lets you "contain" any associated data you'd like.  Instead of "recursive", which blindly pulls entire levels of data (and can often cause memory errors), "Containable" allows you to specify EXACTLY what data you want to retrieve even down to the field(s) if you'd like.

Basically, you set your model to `public $actsAs = array('Containable');`  (I suggest doing that in your AppModel so Containable is available for all models).  Then, you pass a "contain" array/nested array of the associated models you want to retrieve (see below example).

After reading about it and following the instructions, your code should look similar to this:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    if(empty($id)) $this->redirect('/');

    $season = $this->Season->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Season.id' => $id
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Standing' => array(
                'Team'
            )
        )
    );
    $this->set(compact('season'));
}
```

Once you get more comfortable with CakePHP, you should really move functions like this into the model instead of having them in the controller (search for "CakePHP Fat Models Skinny Controllers"), but for now, just get it working. :)

Comment: Hey! It works like a charm! Exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot for the detail explanation and advices! :) (I still need to spend some time to digest the solution though, hehe)

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$this->Season->id = $id;
$this->Season->recursive = 2;
$this->set('season', $this->Season->read());
```

Comment: (-1 for recursive=2)  Recursive 2 is never a good idea.  They're supposedly even removing the 'recursive' idea alltogether in cakephp 3.